# how to list a range of numbers in file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file named example.txt and inside the file I have numbers from 1 -50 but I only want to view number within a particular range like 1-25

I tried this command:
`less example.txt | grep [1-25]`

but this didn't help, please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO the best way would be to use mathematical condition check rather than regex, please try following `awk` program.

```
awk '$0>=0 && $0<=25' Input_file
```

Above will work if your lines are containing only digits eg:

```
1
2
3
.....
```

In case your Input_file's lines can contain multiple digits that you want to print then better to loop through them and apply conditions to them and print them then.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i>=0 && $i<=25){print $i}}}' Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! That worked fine for me!

Comment: Sure.
Please is there a way to add the count to that command so it lists out the counts of those numbers on the terminal? eg 1-20 , 2-22, 3-23 etc

Answer (score 1):

`[1-25]` means match group of characters consisting of characters between `1` and `2` and character `5`. It's the same as `[125]` - match any of `1` `2` or `5`.

You can:

```
grep '[1-9]\|1[0-9]\|2[0-5]'
```

Match digits 1 to 9, or match 1 followed by digit 0 to 8, or match 2 followed by digit 0 to 5. Maybe add `-w`, see `man grep`.

I recommend regex crosswords for learning regex.